# Java - Stanford NLP - Process all files in directory

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford to do some NER analysis on txt files. The problem so far is that I have been to read all files in a directory. I have just been able to read simple Strings. What should be the next step to read several files? I tried with Iterator but it did not work.

Please see my code below:

> Blockquote

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.SentimentAnnotator;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier;
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.NamedEntityTagAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBEscapingProcessor;
import edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.DocumentPreprocessor;
import edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import com.google.common.io.Files;
import org.apache.commons.io.*;


public class NLPtest2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse, ner, dcoref, sentiment");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

        //how can we read all documents in a directory instead of just a String??

       String text = "I work at Lalalala Ltd. It is awesome"; 

        Annotation annotation = new Annotation(text);

        pipeline.annotate(annotation);

       // Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(text);
        List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

        for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
            String sentiment = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentClass.class);
            System.out.println(sentiment + "\t" + sentence);
           // System.out.println(annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.QuotationsAnnotation.class));// dont need it
                  // traversing the words in the current sentence
                  // a CoreLabel is a CoreMap with additional token-specific methods
                  for (CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
                    // this is the text of the token
                    String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);

                    // this is the POS tag of the token
                    String pos = token.get(PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
                    // this is the NER label of the token

                    String ne = token.get(NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class); 
                    System.out.println( "Text:"+ word +"//"+"Part of Speech:"+ pos + "//"+ "Entity Recognition:"+ ne);
                  }

            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to read files in Java? Have you tried searching for that?

Comment: @pvg , thanks for your comment. My problem is that I dont know how to read the file sentence by sentence and not line by line with the code above. Cheers

Comment: I can't find i/o code in the snippet you have posted at all.

Comment: My input is :   String text = "I work at Lalalala Ltd. It is awesome"; and the output shown in the console is the split by sentence and words. However, I would like to read by sentence all documents  in one directory and print it. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: You should include the code of your attempt of reading the files and any specific problems you have  run into. As it is, it still looks like you're asking someone to write this for you which isn't really what SO is for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

import java.util.*;

public class ReadFiles {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> filePaths = IOUtils.linesFromFile(args[0]);
    for (String filePath : filePaths) {
      String fileContents = IOUtils.stringFromFile(filePath);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @stanfordnlphelp. However, I havent been able to implement this on my code. May you be more specific on which part I would need to change? Cheers

Comment: In your example you run StanfordCoreNLP on the variable "text".  My code shows how to open up a list of files, read each file, and get the contents of the file as a String.  So you would run your code on "fileContents" in my example.  Note that the list of files is supposed to be supplied in args[0], which is the first argument of the main() method for my demo class.